# Leader Election SolrCloud + Zookeeper

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solr4

I have a working Zookeeper ensemble running with 3 instances and also a solrcloud cluster with some solr instances.
I've created a collection with settings to 2 shards. Then i:

```
create 1 core on instance1
create 1 core on instance2
create 1 core on instance1
create 1 core on instance2
```

Just to have this configuration:

```
instance1: shard1_leader, shard2_replica
instance2: shard1_replica, shard2_leader
```

If i add 2 cores to instance1 then 2 cores to instance2, both leaders will be on instance1 and  no re-election is done.

```
instance1: shard1_leader, shard2_leader
instance2: shard1_replica, shard2_replica
```

Back to my ideal scenario (detached leaders), also when i add a third instance with 2 replicas and kill one of my instances running a leader, the election picks the instance that already have a leader.

My question is why Zookeeper takes this behavior. Shouldn't it distribute leaders?
If i deliver some stress to a double-leader instance, is Zookeeper going to run an election?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got this answer from Erick Ericson, on lucene forum:

This is probably not all that important to worry about. The additional 
duties of a leader are pretty minimal. And the leaders will shift around 
anyway as you restart servers etc. Really feels like a premature 
optimization.

Comment: You should accept this answer. This will show other people that an acceptable answer exist